# How to update bytea data in Postgres table?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to import contents of a file locally stored into a column of a row in a table.
The type of column is bytea.

Something like:

```
UPDATE server_info
SET key = lo_import('C:\Users\certificate.p12')
WHERE server_id = 1;
```

However, it gives below error:

```
ERROR:  column "key" is of type bytea but expression is of type oid
```

I tried casting. Used below line for it:

```
UPDATE server_info
SET key = lo_import('C:\Users\certificate.p12')::bytea
WHERE server_id = 1;
```

But it gives:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type oid to bytea
```

I am new to using Postgres. Any leads in this matter will be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Which SQL client are you using? Some support that kind of "uploading" files into a bytea column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using pgAdmin 4 as client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that with just SQL.

You'll have to write a program in the language of your choice that reads the files into memory and uses that as parameter to an `INSERT`.

Comment: Okay. That way I am able to do it i.e. using a program. But wanted to know if it is possible via just SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to do it just with an SQL, you could first import it as an oid and then convert it to a bytea. But this a little bit weired.

```
ALTER TABLE server_info add column key_bytea bytea
UPDATE server_info SET key_bytea = lo_get(key)
ALTER TABLE server_info drop column key
ALTER TABLE server_info rename column key_bytea to key
```